# how to get Power BI Report Data using Rest API

Tags: rest, api, powerbi

I have created a Report on Power BI Desktop
This was then published to My Workspace.
I need the Steps to get the Report data in json or csv formats

Answer (score 0):

Power BI REST API doesn't support that. You should get the data by connecting directly to the same data source used in this report.

The other way is in browser to click the ellipsis in the top right corner of the visual:

[image]

And export the data.

Comment: is any Java Sdk available to get data

Comment: What is the datasource?

Comment: xls file and Mssql currently use

Comment: For [XML](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/) and for [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-to-sql-server-with-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-2017)